# Zabbix action debugging

Tags: zabbix

Is there any way to debug zabbix (4.0) custom script?
In action log I see only "timeout" message but I would like to see exactly what went wrong. I do not have access to zabbix log.

Comment: Run the script manually and see what part is running for longer than the timeout. The default timeout is 3 seconds.

Comment: @IronBishop I do not have ssh access on this machine. Really, no possibility to debug on zabbix??

Comment: It's a custom script, so it's not part of Zabbix. Running it with `system.run[]` still has a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Zabbix.Log it is like console.log in javascript.
Example:

```
Zabbix.Log(4, '[ Custom Script Log ] Log Initiated.. ');
```